# Can't see my session values in the after login page

Tags: php, session

I have a login page where when a username and password are correct, I save the id and username of the logged person in sessions:

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username= :u AND password= :p");
$result->bindParam(':u', $user);
$result->bindParam(':p', $password);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if($rows > 0) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['login_id'] = $id_logged;
    header("location: ./pages/home.php");
}
```

In `home.php` I am trying to echo those 2 sessions:

```
<?php 
require_once('../include/global.php');
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$id_logged = $_SESSION['login_id'];
echo $dentist_user;
echo $id_logged;
?>
```

But I only see the username without its ID.

`global.php` code is:

```
<?php

session_start();

    $DB_host = "localhost";
    $DB_user = "";
    $DB_pass = "";
    $DB_name = "";
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['login_id'])){
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
    else{
        try
        {
             $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
             $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
             $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
             echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where are you receiving this $id_logged while setting that to $_SESSION['login_id']?

Comment: Where is your `$dentist_user` defined?

Comment: you have to respond to @EdwinAlex and also **NEVER STORE PASSWORD**, instead, use md5 or any other hashing algorithme....

Comment: use session_start(); where you get the query result

Comment: Well, I will respond to all of you @HalayemAnis relax. Yeah I used the md5 hashing. Then, I used session_start() but still the same result

Comment: @EdwinAlex I didn't understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @androidnation Well. I will explain in detail. $_SESSION['login_id'] = $id_logged; in this line how do you get the value for $id_logged? Where it is set? I am not able to find that in your code. Also, did you check $id_logged value?

Comment: `$id_logged` is empty. Well when a user logged in with a username and password, in mysql their is a field called `login_id`, so when the login is successful I need to send the username and and the id of the user, because this `login_id` column is a foreign key in another tables.

Comment: `$_SESSION['username']` isn't empty, but `$_SESSION['login_id']` is empty

Comment: @androidnation That's the issue.. Check that.

Comment: I know that is the issue, that's why I asked here for help.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and make sure the session was started in **all** pages using sessions.